# Adfv2 reference child pipeline variable in master pipeline

Tags: variables, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that executes another pipeline in azure data factory v2. In the executed (child) pipeline I assign a value to a variable I want returned in the master pipeline, is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pipelines are independent entities - while you can execute "child" pipelines, there is no functional connection between the two. One way around this is to have the child pipeline write the value to some form of intermediate storage (blob storage, a SQL table, etc), and then have the "parent" pipeline read the value after the child pipeline completes. You should also make sure the Execute Pipeline activity has the "Wait on completion" property checked. If you don't want the value retained in the storage medium, you could have the parent pipeline delete the data once it has processed it.